# Using Volley in an app with RecyclerViews and Fragments - Baking App

Tags: android

In a simple toy app that I made to test volley I could easily retrieve JSON data from the link given by Udacity for use in its Baking app.
However in my actual Baking App I cannot seem to use Volley. From the logs it seems that Volley does not actually retrieve the JSON from the link, even though the same code was working in my toy app.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.android.bakingapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements RecipeListFragment.OnListFragmentInteractionListener {

    String json;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://d17h27t6h515a5.cloudfront.net/topher/2017/May/59121517_baking/baking.json";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        json = response;
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                json="";
            }
        });

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
        RecipeJson.setJsonData(json);

        RecipeListFragment recipeListFragment = new RecipeListFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, recipeListFragment)
                .commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onListFragmentInteraction(DummyContent.DummyItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipeDetails.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", item.id);
        RecipeDetails.counter = 0;
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

RecipeJson.java:

```
package com.example.android.bakingapp;

public class RecipeJson {
    public static String jsonData;
    public static void setJsonData(String json){
        jsonData=json;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
08-09 23:09:35.050 2181-2181/com.example.android.bakingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.bakingapp, PID: 2181
    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.RecipeListFragment.onCreateView(RecipeListFragment.java:68)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1382)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:194)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:157)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:72)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
        at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent.makeJsonArray(DummyContent.java:55)
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.dummy.DummyContent.<clinit>(DummyContent.java:28)
        at com.example.android.bakingapp.RecipeListFragment.onCreateView(RecipeListFragment.java:68) 
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2346) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1428) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827) 
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3248) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3200) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:195) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1382) 
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2949) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:194) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:180) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:157) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:72) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
```

The culprit line is this:

```
jsonArray = new JSONArray(RecipeJson.jsonData);
```

The logs indicate that nothing is being stored in jsonData. 
But why is that?

Comment: Post your 'RecipeListFragment'

Answer (score 0):

As @prashant17 alluded to, onResponse() is asynchronous. That means any code placed after the stringRequest may be executed prior to the jsonRequest execution. Thus, all code that works with the String json must be placed in onResponse. This includes your fragment transactions.

Related to the culprit line of code you provided, be wary of passing an abstract class reference to the JSONArray constructor, rather than an instance of the object whose data has previously been set. Your code looks like you are doing the former.

Answer (score 0):

Move your `RecipeJson.setJsonData(json);` inside `onResponse`.

As Volley is `asynchronous`. with your current implementation `json string` is always `null`